# Should an insert method return an object or throw exceptions

Tags: c#, api, design-patterns

I'm designing an API (first time) and it'll be a very public one (for a free online service).

I'm considering between returning structures such as `InsertResult` which can have the properties for when it fails or succeed (i.e. how much rows), the error messages and so on. Now, the other way is to just throw exceptions from the API insert method. I know this is kind of a "general and open" question but, what is considered more clean and polished for an API?

**Scenario**

The API is a DLL (which internally calls and consume Web Services from 4 or 5 different sources and that depending on things like geolocation decides which service to interact with). It's built using C# and Mono. Usage scenarios includes the API as library from desktop, mobile and web clients. That's indeed the problem, suppose an offline use case, from the web client it simply won't happen but from the mobile or desktop it can (from the mobile more frequently) what to do then? how to manage say an Insert call to store a mock from a mobile app just when it got offline. Or when another (server related) error happens.

Comment: What does the API do?  I normally look at it as if it is a service someone is consuming (web service), return useful information if it failed.  If you are designing a Framework, you should throw exceptions as the developer may want to deal with it in different ways.

Comment: @Justin The API exposes our WebServices to manage the documents (think of jet another icloud or dropbox but to store UI sketches).

Comment: Do you mean for the consumer to handle an exception, or for you to handle the exception and relay the message to the consumer?

Comment: @Cory The point is that it's pretty hard to know. Suppose that they're using the API from a mobile app and the app got disconnected. Then I must manage the exception internally, but if the problem is with their input, then, how to deal with that?

Comment: What "language" is your API going to communicate with? What sort of technologies will be consuming the service? You could always do *both* by injecting a 500 error code in the response header **and** return an object with the details of the exception.

Comment: @Cory see the edit. Is a POCL.

Comment: The consumer should deal with connection problems -- you can't really do anything about that anyway. It will be up to you to validate user request input and to relay exception messages back to the consumer. If you have a broad range unknown consumer technologies, I would entertain the idea I commented on before. Return response content that represents the error, but change the response headers to make it seem to the consumer that an exception occurred.

Comment: @RandolfR-F Can you clarify 'API' for us?  Are you actually making a framework (dll) that will be consumed or is it a set of web services?

Comment: @Justin The API is a DLL (which internally calls and consume Web Services from 4 or 5 different sources and that depending on things like geolocation decides which service to interact with)

Comment: @RandolfR-F: That changes things. If your API is a DLL, throw custom exceptions that inherit ApplicationException.

Comment: @RandolfR-F I have updated my anwser, but your API is a framework which random clients won't consume.  It will be developers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, you should throw an exception if the user tried to do something that is invalid. 
However, you should also provide a code path that allows the user to reasonably check for conditions which could throw an exception before they occur. If it's important (possibly for performance reasons) you might want to include a `TryInsert` method which safely handles invalid inserts and simply returns a `bool` valid to indicate success.

This applies to pure C# API's as well as service API's.

Comment: I didn't even consider the TryInsert, looks as a natural way of make a safe route to; but, isn't providing 2 options for the same thing just getting messier the decision?

Comment: @RandolfR-F Consider wrapping the request / response parameters in wrappers classes. You can specify `ThrowOnError` or something like that as an optional parameter and still have a single service call.

Answer (score 2):

Throwing exceptions is the more *natural* way of handling errors and unexpected situations in C#/.NET. In addition, .NET provides you with the possibility to define your own exceptions or use one of the already existing ones.
Additionally by providing things like `finally{}`-blocks you can create really smooth goings when something goes wrong.
Checking return values is error-prone and it might make the process unstable, if the user does not react to your return-values properly. An unhandled exception usually stops the process and so Forces the user to check on the Background. That's my opinion, though.

On [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173163%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) they say, that it is quite a reason to throw an exception, if for example a Parameter is wrong and you cannot continue with wrong Input.

Comment: Your answer is accurate but I'm not sure it pertains to the question being asked. The question is about how to properly relay failure information to the consumer of a web service.

Comment: Well, sometimes I'll have a hit, too^^

Comment: @Cory as I don't know any specific things I cannot answer that specifically. Are you 100% sure about this?

Comment: @Cory when an exception occurs the service host (e.g. WCF) should be responsible for reasonably turning the exception into a form the client can consume.

Comment: @p.s.w.g: True, but I don't doubt that the OP knows how to throw and catch exceptions. I feel that the question is about how to convey the errors (let the consumer handle an error vs. let the consumer know what the error message was). The question is pretty vague.

Comment: @Cory What's the difference between those two? The consumer can correctly handle the error if and only if it knows what the error message was. The question is how make the service support that most effectively.

Comment: @p.s.w.g That's precisely the problem.

Comment: @p.s.w.g: You mentioned WCF services. In that instance, it would be perfectly acceptable to throw an Exception, wrap it up in a FaultContract and force the consumer to deal with a runtime exception. But what if the OP's API communicates only with JSON and the consumer is just a JavaScript AJAX request or a language I just made up that doesn't know how to handle exceptions? I think the appropriate thing to do would be to provide the consumer with a message containing the error without actually throwing an exception. The technologies will greatly influence a "correct" answer.

Comment: FWIW OP just edited and said his API is a framework wrapped up in a DLL. Given the new information, throwing and catching exceptions is likely the right answer.

Answer (score 2):

As the question is "general and open" i think if we consider most used webservices like google,amazon i think they all follow the principle of giving details as precise as possible so anyone who is consuming it know what they are doing wrong.

If you just trow the exception it might be users of your API will bug you more.

So just to summarize its always a Good idea to define well known error codes and pass the same information to the client/consumer so they can easily figure out what is wrong with the call or what should i do to correct it.
just for an example for some reason your api only accept specific encoding then user will be frustrated with that.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend returning a detailed error.  Since you are using a web service for consumption, not everyone will be using the same technology to interact with it.  If you where making a framework, then I would say use exceptions as the developers would be using the same technologies to consume it.  This is where exceptions are more useful, at a framework level.

**UPDATED (The API in question is actually a framework):**
Since you are now talking about using a framework, you should throw exceptions as the clients have to reference the DLL and will have knowledge of the possible framework exception.  To use the libraries it would have to be a CLR-compliant language so they should have the same concepts, classes, exceptions, etc...

Answer (score 0):

For API, exception is always better. The API consumer can act upon various exceptions using catch blocks. If you use error message and error codes, you are asking your API consumer to write If statements. the snippet below is always cleaner than something where you have If condition to check error.

Hence from API consumer point of view its always cleaner that API throws exception

```
try
{
    yourAPIClass.YourMethod();
}
catch(YourException1 ex)
{
   action1();

}
catch(YourException2 ex)
{
   action1();

}
```

Here's a good guideline for writing and throwing exceptions 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kcwalina/archive/2005/03/16/396787.aspx